# Adding List Item (Div) with a Variable from a Prompt (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a class assignment, and each of the "Add Task" buttons need to have a prompt show up (which I have done), and the item that is entered needs to be added to the bottom of the respective lists.

I have tried the appendTo and append options, but I am not sure how to append my variables item1, and item2 to their respective lists.

```
$("#add1").click(function(){
    var item1 = prompt ("What task would you like to give Kelly?");
});
```

Here's the problem via JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/70nspbnr/)

Comment: You know you can (should) put the HTML, CSS and JSS directly in your question? You can still run it like a jsfiddle. You should definitely show your attempt at `appendTo` and describe how it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I notice that most people tend to just use jsfiddle, wasn't aware that that wasn't correct. Norlihazmey answered it superbly though, so I assume no harm no foul.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want, try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70nspbnr/1/). What you want need to do is using [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method and append it using the variable **item1** and **item2** as following code  :

```
 $("#add1").click(function(){
    var item1 = prompt ("What task would you like to give Kelly?");
    $('#employee1').append('<div class="ui-state-default"><p>'+item1+'</p></div>');
});

$("#add2").click(function(){
    var item2 = prompt ("What task would you like to give Estelle?");
    $('#employee2').append('<div class="ui-state-default"><p>'+item2+'</p></div>');
});
```

Comment: That's perfect. For some reason I had typed that, but it didn't go through correctly. I am thinking I messed up the " and ' somehow. Didn't close the right ones yadda yadda.

Comment: You should check out the example provided and see the difference line by line and put into your actual code.